# installing a new extension

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

magento v1.7.0.2
get this error when trying to install a new extension. I just want to take the site offline/ permanent maintenance mode.

any help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: much harder to read than plaintext.  tddr.

Comment: Did you manage to get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Magento logs and the reports if there is any specific error thrown.

Next to that, if you want to take the site offline you can always add the `maintenance.flag` file to your shops root directory